# How to monitor data traffic in WAN using splunk?

Tags: splunk, splunk-dashboard

My task is actually for self learning, I know the basics of Splunk and how does it work, overall it needs logs then further analysis is future part.

Right now, I am working in a small company without specific firewall device, just the router is there, I am planning to keep real time track of internet speed + data usage by each hosts and similar things, overall say I want to monitor all the network usage in this small WAN environment.

My question is, as splunk need logs then how can I get the log of all the network flow when there is just a router but no external device to create logs, that can be feeded to splunk later?

I tried google but there I find only preset softwares that automatically capture logs and show analysis while I just need logs only.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a way to get logs off your router to *somewhere* Splunk can parse them

*Most typically*, this is done by sending the router's syslog messages to a syslog collector like [SC4S](https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/4740).

From there, Splunk can then get the messages processed and ingested for anaylsis